Unable to start an activity in Android Studio
I'm new to Android Development and was trying to create an application where on clicking a button, we a re-directed to another activity. On running the app in a VM, the initial MainActivity runs with no errors but the SecondPage is not running.
Here are the error logs:
Process: com.example.luckynumber, PID: 32726
                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.luckynumber/com.example.luckynumber.SecondPage}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5f
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
                 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5f
                    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:444)
                    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6412)
                    at com.example.luckynumber.SecondPage.onCreate(SecondPage.java:42)
                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
                    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
                    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 

Manifest File:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.LuckyNumber"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondPage"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

This is the code for my MainActicity:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView displayText;
    EditText inputName;
    Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        displayText=findViewById(R.id.displayText);
        inputName=findViewById(R.id.inputName);
        btn1=findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToSecondPage();
            }
        });

    }
    public void goToSecondPage(){
        String userName=inputName.getText().toString();
        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                SecondPage.class);
        intent.putExtra("name",userName);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

}

Here is the SecondPage:
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_page);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });
        displayLucky=findViewById(R.id.displayLucky);
        luckyNumber=findViewById(R.id.luckyNumber);
        btn2=findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String userName=intent.getStringExtra("name");

        int randomNumber=generateRandomNumber();

        luckyNumber.setText(randomNumber);

        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                shareData(userName,randomNumber);

            }
        });


    }

    public int generateRandomNumber(){
        Random random=new Random();
        int upper_limit=100;

        return random.nextInt(upper_limit);
    }

    public void shareData(String username,int num){
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setType("text/plain");

        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,username+" got lucky today");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"His lucky number is "+num);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"Choose a platform"));

    }
}


This question is similar to: Getting android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: exception even when the resource is present in android. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The problem is caused by the flexibility of androids TextView.setText() function.
There are multiple versions of it that you can pass many different types to.
One of these versions accepts an Integer reference to a String resource.
Because you are passing it an Integer generated by your generateRandomNumber() function this is the version that is used and so this function looks for a string resource matching the id, hence the error Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x5f
To solve this you should change the line setting the text to luckyNumber.setText(String.valueOf(randomNumber)) and this will solve it
